# \includegraphics doesn't work anymore

Tags: graphics, miktex, texmaker

I'm using Texmaker + MikTex on Windows. A couple of years ago I've written my thesis successfully. Now I have to write another one, so I've copied the structure of the previous one and modified it. One thing I've noticed is that the \includegraphics doesn't work anymore. I have the caption but not the picture, it only shows a white box. I've recompiled my previous original thesis and the pictures are gone too. I've tried removing the graphics and graphicx files from miktex and redownloaded them but it didn't work.
The code used is:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,natwidth=650,natheight=251]{ZeusCompare.jpg}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

Any idea on what I could do? The file is in the same folder as the latex file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Look for a `draft` option somewhere.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Are you compiling with pdflatex, latex, or something else?

Comment: Don't use the natwidth and natheight keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `natheight` and `natwidth` keys are wrong here. While they didn't do harm in the past they currently lead to missing images (this will perhaps change in the future).